# Evaluating mcar values in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I have:

> (equal? 'ignored (mcar q))

where

> >(mcar q)
>
> {ignored}

But this comparison never evaluates properly.  I have tried other comparators also, but nothing seems to evaluate to true.  What am I doing wrong?

I'm in Swindle.

Comment: What does "never evaluates properly" mean?

Comment: I mean, I would expect it to evaluate to true but it always evaluates to false

Comment: What is the value of `q`? `{ignored}` appears to be a special value that is not a symbol. Is `(symbol? (mcar q))`, `#f`?

Comment: q  -> {{ignored} ignored} and yes, (symbol? (mcar q)) -> #f.  Can you explain to me why this is?

Answer (score 2):

`{{ignored} ignored}` is Racket's printer output for the mutable version of `((ignored) ignored)`. Let's use the normal cons cells version to answer this.

With `((ignored) ignored)`, the `car` of that is `(ignored)` and not `ignored`, so your comparison would indeed be false. But you can get `ignored` two ways: 1. using `caar` (`(car (car x))`), or 2. using `cadr` (`(car (cdr x))`).